# Added a file to Android project on one computer, did SVN update, and now showing up in Eclipse on second computer?

Tags: android, eclipse, tortoisesvn

I created an xml file on one computer in Eclipse for an android project, and then did an SVN commit to upload it.  Then I updated on my second computer (which previously wasn't showing anything at all in the project explorer but I fixed that by adding .project and .classpath to the syncing) but the new file isn't showing up in Eclipse.  It's definitely in the folder, but it's not showing it.

I turned all the filters off, still not showing.  I tried importing files but wouldn't let me import anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be one of a few things going on here.

If you did the SVN update from the command line, make sure the file is in the directory that you expect from the command line as well before checking eclipse.  If the file is indeed there then you probably need to do a "refresh" on the project in Eclipse (Right Click project in Package Explorer, then click "Refresh").  If you do that and it doesn't show, check your project properties in eclipse and make sure the path for the project matches the path you are doing your SVN commandline work from.

If you are doing SVN commands using a plugin in eclipse like subclipse, I recommend doing a Team > Synchronize before making commits and updates so you can see what's coming and going before your project or the repository is affected.  If you try that command and shows your project in sync with the repository, check the repo to make sure that the file is in fact committed there.  Perhaps there was an issue doing the commit from computer 1.